# Intellij: Cannot Run Git File Not Found: /usr/local/bin/git

Tags: git, intellij-idea

In Intellij I'm receiving the error message that is in the title of this question: `Cannot Run Git File Not Found: /usr/local/bin/git`.

The file, however, does exist. I've tried selecting it in the configuration dialog, but without success.

The problem does not seem to be present in VS Code.

Anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to setup git properly, go to Settings, then File | Settings | Version Control | Git and edit *Path to Git executable* field. If you enter path to Git (`which git` in terminal) - usually */usr/bin/git* and press **Test** it may popup a more informative message. Also check the rights of the git executable.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've gone through the Git configuration in preferences and selected the file that exists, but I still get the error. No more info. I should probably have included that Git has been working fine until last week. I was on vacation, so not sure if the problem coincides with updating Intellij a couple weeks ago.

Comment: What `which git` outputs in terminal?

Comment: /usr/bin/git. Interesting. I suppose I should point to that, then.

Comment: Yes! Sorry for not replying sooner! All good. I don't know why it was pointing to the wrong directory. Must have happened during last update.

Comment: `chmod +rwx git` works for making sure the git executable can run.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set correct git executable as shown in the attached screen and it will be ok.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D96nC.png)

Comment: Since that executable does not exist for the OP, perhaps an explanation of how to find it and then add it to the settings in the attached screen?